# How to use a table variable name in dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table variable, which I want to convert into a VARCHAR so that it can be used in a dynamic SQL statement. Here's a simple version of what I'm trying to do, my actual SQL is far more complex than this.

```
DECLARE @tmpSearchTerms TABLE (searchTerm VARCHAR(100))

SET @SQL = ' SELECT * FROM ' + CAST (@tmpSearchTerms AS VARCHAR)

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: you want to change the table variable to varchar or column of a table variable to varchar.

Comment: You can't do such a thing. Your table variable is defined and valid in the scope of the script while the dynamic query you build has another execution scope and cannot access your table variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do what you are doing with a table variable, so use a `#temp` table instead, take a look at this sample code:

```
create table #tmpSearchTerms (searchTerm VARCHAR(100))
insert into #tmpSearchTerms(searchTerm) values('test record')

declare @SQL nvarchar(300)

set @SQL = ' SELECT * FROM #tmpSearchTerms'
exec (@SQL)

drop table #tmpSearchTerms
```

Comment: It's just an example. The query is much complexer and dynamic.

Comment: Really not sure why this deserves a down vote as the question doesn't specify that there is any more complexity to it than this

Comment: The content of @SQL I mean. But if it is not possible. Okay that will be a better answer.

Comment: @user1531040 I'm aware of that but you didn't state that in the question, so how is anyone supposed to know that? Anyhow, my answer has been updated